# I can't get vertical scrolling on my flexdashboard

Tags: r, user-interface, scroll, flexdashboard

I'm trying to set up a [flexdashboard](/questions/tagged/flexdashboard) to convey some information and am having some problems with scrolling. Putting vertical_layout: scroll in the header does no good, it leads to the [flexdashboard](/questions/tagged/flexdashboard) cutting off halfway down the page. When I set `vertical_layout` fill, I can see more info, but it still goes off the page. In neither case is a vertical (or horizontal) scrollbar available to enable the user to see the cut-off information.

Although I have more text than below, this is illustrative of the problem. Does anyone know why this may be happening or if there might be any ways around it? I'm using a tablet currently but have tried using standard columns with no success. The problem is on Page 2. Thanks.

```
---
title: "title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

Introduction
===

Column
---

* some text

Page 2
===

Column {.tabset}
---

### h3
* test

#### h4
* text

#### h4
* text

### h3

#### h4
* some text

#### h4
* some text
```